# SharePoint 2013-Lync2010 - Presence not working for multi user people column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, presence-indication, lync

we have a SharePoint 2013 farm and we use Lync 2010 on our desktops. I am using IE 9 browser to view the site.

I have a team site with a library. To the library, I have added a people column and selected the option to allow multiple users to the field.
I uploaded a document and entered multiple users to the people field. When I select the users, I am able to view their presence indicator, but after saving\uploading the document when I view the properties I don't see the presence indicator. I just see only a gray square box next to their names.

Interestingly, people columns with single user option are displaying the presence indicator with no problem! So it's only the people fields which have the multi-user select option enabled that are having this problem.

Has anyone seen this problem, any suggestions? Is this a SharePoint or Office bug?